# How to hide button/form with django templates?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I want to hide form if user already pushed on the button. I tried to use a bit of JS code, it works well, but after refreshing page, button on form stay valid. It not a huge surprise for me)) I want hide form using Django templates, but it is not so easy as I thought.

my html :

```
    <div class="who_come">

   <p>Who come : </p>
   {% for u in who_come %}
   {%if u.visiter.username != request.user.username %}
   <form class="form-inline" role="form" method="post" id="joinToEventForm">
      {% csrf_token %}
      <p align="left"><b ><button type="submit">I want join</button></b></p></b></p>
   </form>
   {% endif %}
   {% endfor %}
   <div id="who_come_links">
   {% for u in who_come reversed %}
    <p><a href="profile/{{u.visiter.username}}" title="{{u.visiter.first_name}} {{u.visiter.last_name}}">{{u.visiter.username}}</a></p>
   {% endfor %}
   </div>
   <script>
      $('#joinToEventForm').submit(function() {
         $(this).find("button[type='submit']").prop('disabled',true);
      });
   </script>

<script>

   $('#joinToEventForm').on('submit', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log("form submitted!")  // sanity check


   $.ajax({
       type:'POST',
       data:{
           action: 'joinEvent',
           csrfmiddlewaretoken:'{{ csrf_token }}'
       },

       success : function (data) {
           //console.log(data);

           var usernames = JSON.parse(data);
           var html_str = '';

           for (var i=0; i < usernames.length; i++) {
               html_str += '<p><a href="profile/' + usernames[i] + '">' + usernames[i] + '</a></p>';
           }

           $('#who_come_links').html(html_str);

           }


   });
});
</script>

</div>
```

my model :

```
class WhoComeOnEvent(models.Model):
    visiter = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='WhoComeOnEvent')
    which_event = models.ForeignKey(Topic, related_name='WhoComeOnEvent')
```

in this place :

```
<p>Who come : </p>
       {% for u in who_come %}
       {%if u.visiter.username != request.user.username %}
       <form class="form-inline" role="form" method="post" id="joinToEventForm">
          {% csrf_token %}
          <p align="left"><b ><button type="submit">I want join</button></b></p></b></p>
       </form>
       {% endif %}
       {% endfor %}
```

i tried to check who already joined to event and if user that do request same that user in database table, then hide form. But this code doesn't work. It hide form no matter if user exist in db table or not. Second part is that has no connection to current event. Suppose django template that hide form in my case will work. It will check only row in table but it will ignore current it event or it different event (not sure, but i'm afraid of it).

my view :

```
def p(request, pk):
    user = request.user
    topic = get_object_or_404(Topic, pk=pk)
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=pk)
    comment = Comments.objects.filter(pk=pk)
    who_come = WhoComeOnEvent.objects.filter(which_event=topic.id)

    if request.is_ajax() and request.POST.get('action') == 'joinEvent':
        who_come_obj = WhoComeOnEvent.objects.create(
            visiter=user,
            which_event=post.topic
        )

        visitors_usernames = []
        for w in who_come:
            visitors_usernames.append(w.visiter.username)

        return HttpResponse(json.dumps(visitors_usernames))

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CustomCommentForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            comment = form.save(commit=False)
            comment.post = post
            comment.creator = user
            comment = Comments.objects.create(
                body=form.cleaned_data.get('body'),
                creator=user,
                post=post
            )

            return HttpResponseRedirect(request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER'))
            # return render(request, 'post.html', {'post': post, 'topic': topic, 'comment': comment,
            #                                      'form': form, 'who_come': who_come})
    else:
        form = CustomCommentForm()
    return render(request, 'post.html', {'post': post, 'topic': topic, 'comment': comment,
                                         'form': form, 'who_come': who_come})
```

#### Solution:

I found more elegant solution, just adding `.distinct('visitor')` to my who_come queryset.
If someone will read it question and found my solution helpful, notice, that objects still creating to the databese and it doesn't unique!

Comment: why don't you check whether `request.user` is already in the `WhoComeOnEvent` table in your view and send that as a boolean context variable to your template? Like: `if request.user in who_come: is_already_coming = True` then in your template `{% if not is_already_coming %}`

Comment: What's the big difference ? I do the same thing, but without creating new variable

Comment: you should do it for every option in your view. If you refresh the page the flow in your view starts at `else: form = CustomCommentForm()` and your context variable `is_already_coming` is never set. Also when you do the AJAX flow, you never set the context variable. Finally if you use `who_come` in your template, look at your for-loop: you're displaying the button for every user in `who_come` except the logged in user. So that won't work.

Comment: @dirkgroten thanks, i'll try

Comment: @dirkgroten i found more elegant solution, but thanks to you, your answers allowed me to think about a more flexible solution